# Any way to get a warning for static_cast<some_enum_class>(T) where T's type isn't the underlying type of some_enum_class?

Tags: c++, c++20, static-cast, enum-class

I'm reviewing a lot of code where I need to ensure there are no static_cast (or any cast) calls on variables that could be out of range of the enum class that is being cast to. Ideally I'd be able to receive a warning or have some way to detect code that is casting from, for example, an int when the enum class in question has an underlying type of unsigned char.

```
enum class some_enum_class : unsigned char
{
    SomeVal,
};
int BadVal = 1000;
auto EnumVar = static_cast<some_enum_class>(BadVal); //Trigger Warning!
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? (hopefully in MSVC?)

Comment: You can write your own casting function. You can compare the template arguments to check if the first is the same as the second's underlying type with `std::underlying_type`. It won't keep anyone from using `static_cast` but it will detect mistakes if the developer uses the casting function.

Comment: Eljay, changed to 1000 to make it an obvious problem
Fran, I'm changing existing code. If I could overload static_cast that would work, but having a custom casting function does not help.

Comment: There is no other way except for maybe writing clang-tidy plugin. Really what you should do is search all suspicious `static_cast`s in your project and replace them with your function that has `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>, IntType>)` in it.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that if `static_assert` is happening, cast already means that you want the value of this type and nothing else. Custom cast like other commenter suggested or with C++17 you can use [direct list initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#enum_relaxed_init_cpp17) to ensure no narrowing conversion occurs (gcc emits a warning, clang and MSVC an error).

Answer (score 1):

Doing your own casting function can help you, you can wrap the `const_cast` function using concepts and constraints of `c++20` which specifies the requirements on template arguments.
And for example clang tidy recognize it and throw a warning before any compilation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename NewType>
concept isConvertible = std::is_convertible<NewType, T>::value;

template<typename T, typename NewType>
static NewType constraint_static_cast(T t)requires isConvertible<NewType, T>{
    return static_cast<NewType>(t);
}

int main(){
    enum class SomeEnumClass : unsigned char
    {
        SomeValue,
    };
    int bad_value = 1000;
    auto EnumVar = constraint_static_cast<int, SomeEnumClass>(bad_value); //Trigger Warning!
    auto EnumVar = constraint_static_cast<int, bool>(bad_value); //Work because of the concept
}
```